# overcome a div that blocks clicks

Tags: python, selenium

Hello i'm having some problems to click  instagram  buttons.
This is the Html

```html
<div class="_2dDPU" role="dialog">
  <div class="EfHg9">
  </div>
  <div class="zZYga" role="dialog">

  <div class="PdwC2 HYpXt" role="dialog">
    <div class="t48Bo fzjDT">Follower</div>
  <div class="j6cq2"><ul class="SrXZj YHaCL">
  <ul class="SrXZj YHaCL">
    <div class="_1xe_U">
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
    <li class="NroHT">
      <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   ">Segui</button>
  </ul>
```

my code is this

```
 try:
        #Search button

        segui = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(segui_css_selector)
        time.sleep(5)

    #except NoSuchElementException scroll the table

    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath (tabella_xpath).click ()
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector (tabella_css_selector)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        elem.send_keys (Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

    #If it founds the button click it

    else:
        segui.click()
        time.sleep (5)
        a+=1
        print (a)
        time.sleep (5)
```

The problem is that it founf the button but it gives me this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX KUBKM      yZn4P   "> is not clickable at point (1088.86669921875,155) because another element <div class="_2dDPU"> obscures it
```

the code sometimes works clicking the button and other times it doesn't work, on some pages it works all the times on other pages never idk why...

this is the element that blocks the click, it's a transparent division that contains the iframe table, i don't know how to pass it.

[image]

this is the list of buttons that the code have to click

[image]

Comment: I suggest a workaround while you don't found the best approach. Edit the buton css to a z-index higher than that div, and you will be able to click on it. Also, your problem is about how instagram css works, so I don't think that there is a better approach that does not use a JS execution.

Comment: and with java what i can do?